# Sequence of functions which approximate analytic function

Tags: analyticity

Consider the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ on the annulus $A=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : \frac{1}{2} \lt{\vert{z}\vert} \lt2\}$.

Which of the following are true?

1. There is a sequence $\{P_n(z)\}_n$ of polynomials that approximate $f(z)$ uniformly on compact subsets of $A$.
2. There is a sequence $\{r_n(z)\}_n$ of rational functions, whose poles are contained in $\mathbb{C}\setminus A$ and which approximates $f(z)$ uniformly on compact subsets of $A$.
3. No sequence $\{P_n(z)\}_n$ of polynomials that approximate $f(z)$ uniformly on compact subsets of $A$.
4. No sequence $\{r_n(z)\}_n$ of rational functions, whose poles are contained in $\mathbb{C}\setminus A$ and which approximate $f(z)$ uniformly on compact subsets of $A$.

I know that every continuous function can be approximated by sequence of polynomials and given function is analytic in annulus A. But how to construct such sequence of functions?

Can we use identity theorem?

Comment: You are supposed to start from $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z}dz = 2i\pi$ and $\int_{|z|=1} P(z)dz = 0$. Also 2. and 4. are indeed trivial.

Comment: Question 5. same questions with $A = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \frac{1}{2} \lt{\vert{z}\vert} \lt2, \Re(z) > 0\}$ and $A' = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \frac{1}{2} \lt{\vert{z}\vert} \lt2, z \not \in (\frac12,2)\}$ (hint : simply connected)

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Consider the [Runge's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_theorem) and its corollary about polynomials.

As regards 1) note that if $\{P_n(x)\}_n$ is a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly to $1/z$ on the compact set $K=\{|z|=r\}\subset A$, for $r\in (1/2,2)$, then we get the contradiction
$$0=\int_{|z|=r}P_n(z)\, dz\to \int_{|z|=r}\frac{1}{z}\,dz=2\pi i\not=0.$$
On the other hand, by Runge's Theorem, the approximation by polynomials to $1/z$ can be done on the compact sets $K$ of $A$ such that $\mathbb{C}\setminus K$ is connected.

Comment: @dipali mali Any more doubts?

Comment: got it . thanks

Comment: How to prove option 2

Comment: @BalasubramannyanS Use Runge's Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_theorem

Comment: @Robert Z how could you integrate 1/z on circular region,,,,,it should be calculate on annulus region,,,,and on which 1/z is already analytic,,by Cauchy gaursat,, integration is 0,,,

Comment: @ Robert Z can you please prove this contradiction , by any other rules!!